# Probablities related to selecting k items from set of n items with non uniform probablity

Tags: probability

Suppose there is a set of $n$ items and we select $k$($1 \le k \le n$) items from this set. The probability of selecting $i^{th}$ item is $p_i$($\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1$).

Then what is the probability that:

1. Given a set of k items, what is the probability that these k items
   were selected
2. $i^{th}$ item is present in selection

If the probabilities were uniform then the answer to these questions would be $\frac {1} {\LARGE{n \choose k}}$  and $\frac {\LARGE{n-1 \choose k-1}} {\LARGE{n \choose k}}$

But what if the probabilities are non-uniform? It looks like a standard question to me but I couldn't find answer to these questions anywhere.

Comment: The phrase "The probability of selecting ith item is $p_i$" is very unclear. You select items one by one or all at the same time? With or without replacement?

Comment: We do one of following(I think they are equivalent):
1. select one by one without replacement and order doesn't matter
2. select all at the same time

Comment: $p_i$ is the probability that an item is selected if picked first. For subsequent selections it can be considered as weight of that this item gets selected

Comment: So suppose if k = 2. then the probability of us selecting item1 and item2 would be $p_1 * p_2/(1-p_1) + p_2 * p_1/(1-p_2)$ (probability of selecting item2 after item1 and vice versa)